# STM32: analog watchdog does only trigger interrupt HAL_ADC_LevelOutOfWindowCallback once

Tags: stm32, watchdog, adc, hal, nucleo

### Question

- Do I need to reset the analog watchdog each time it triggers an
  interrupt or is there an error in my code ?
- If I need to reset it every time how would I do that ?
- Is there a HAL function for it that I can call in the callback?

### My Code

#### Main

```
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
```

#### ADC and WDG Config

```
static void MX_ADC2_Init(void){
  ADC_AnalogWDGConfTypeDef AnalogWDGConfig = {0};
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /** Common config*/
  hadc2.Instance = ADC2;
  hadc2.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc2.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_8B;
  hadc2.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc2.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc2.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc2.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc2.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc2.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analog WatchDog 1 */
  AnalogWDGConfig.WatchdogNumber = ADC_ANALOGWATCHDOG_1;
  AnalogWDGConfig.WatchdogMode = ADC_ANALOGWATCHDOG_SINGLE_REG;
  AnalogWDGConfig.HighThreshold = 64-1;
  AnalogWDGConfig.LowThreshold = 0;
  AnalogWDGConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  AnalogWDGConfig.ITMode = ENABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_AnalogWDGConfig(&hadc2, &AnalogWDGConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc2, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

#### The Callback

```
void HAL_ADC_LevelOutOfWindowCallback (ADC_HandleTypeDef * hadc){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code... specifically...

```
hadc2.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV
```

You probably just need to call start again after the interrupt...

```
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
```